# why has output data row shifted one cell down?

Tags: sas

I am working with the simplest program of finding the average of all the scores eliminating the lowest two.

```
data new;
low1=smallest(1,score_1-score_6);
low2=smallest(2,score_1-score_6);
tot=score_1+score_2+score_3+score_4+score_5+score_6;
avg=(tot-low1-low2)/4;
set mydata;
run;
```

'mydata' does not contain any missing values yet in the output table the data is shifted by one cell down.
the output looks like dis

`id  low1 score_1 score_2 score_3 score_4 score_5 score_6  low2   tot   avg`

```
1    .    0       0     10        80        0      75     .      .     .
2    0    0       0     0          75      80      0      0     165   41.25
3    0    0       50     10        60      55      0      0     155   38.25
4...and so on
```

sas generates a note like this:
NOTE: Missing values were generated as a result of performing an operation on missing values

i cant figure why are the calculated values getting printed in line 2 instead starting in line 1?
help would be appreciated .thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the SET statement right after the DATA statement (which is, I think, generally a good idea).  As you have it, the first row is trying to create a variable but doesn't have any data; the data is only being read at the end.